# Missing link between Homebrew packages

Tags: boost, package, homebrew, linker-errors, boost-python

I have both `boost` and `boost-python` installed via `brew` on my MacOS 10.12 Sierra. However, `boost-python` doesn't seem to think that its dependency `boost` is installed:

```
$ brew info boost
boost: stable 1.68.0 (bottled), HEAD
Collection of portable C++ source libraries
https://www.boost.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1 (12,679 files, 401.2MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2017-10-28 at 09:19:27
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1 (13,506 files, 447.7MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-05-18 at 03:58:16
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/boost.rb
==> Dependencies
Optional: icu4c ✔
==> Options
--with-icu4c
    Build regexp engine with icu support
--without-single
    Disable building single-threading variant
--without-static
    Disable building static library variant
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
Building of Boost.Log is disabled because it requires newer GCC or Clang.
==> Analytics
install: 51,109 (30 days), 167,563 (90 days), 648,244 (365 days)
install_on_request: 15,663 (30 days), 48,585 (90 days), 191,757 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)

$ brew info boost-python
boost-python: stable 1.68.0 (bottled), HEAD
C++ library for C++/Python2 interoperability
https://www.boost.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.65.1 (457 files, 25MB)
  Built from source on 2017-10-28 at 09:23:57 with: --with-python3
/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.67.0 (459 files, 17.3MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-05-18 at 03:58:20
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/boost-python.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: boost ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 5,214 (30 days), 16,979 (90 days), 76,707 (365 days)
install_on_request: 3,865 (30 days), 12,416 (90 days), 56,500 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

How do I get `boost-python` to recognize the existence of / link with  its dependency `boost`?

It would be great if I could avoid uninstalling and reinstalling because there are so many other package dependencies on boost that took me a long/difficult time to get working.

I'm doing this because: when compiling [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html), it says `ld: library not found for -lboost_python`. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I managed to make `boost-python` recognize the existence of its dependency `booth`. **Without uninstalling** any of the existing `boost` and `boost-python` packages in Homebrew, I ran the following line

```
brew install --build-from-source -vd boost boost-python
```

This seems to reinstall both packages and cleanly establish that link.

To address the Caffe compilation issue, this command produces files `libboost_python27*` files in `/usr/local/lib`, which I just copied and renamed to `libboost_python*`.